# Prevent External Google Doc Shares from Arriving via Email

Tags: exchange, cloud, google

We have been receiving a large number of malicious Google Docs being shared to our users via external phishing emails and are looking for a way to prevent these from coming through our Exchange server. We have internal users who share Google Docs between one another and need to retain that functionality, while preventing Google Docs from arriving from external contacts.
Has anyone figured out how to implement this in a corporate environment?

Comment: Are you using gsuite, or are you sharing from individual accounts? If gsuite, you [can disallow external shares (6b)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en)

Comment: Many enterprise grade Web Proxy solutions allow you to add tenant restrictions, for example https://docs.umbrella.com/umbrella-user-guide/docs/control-cloud-access-to-google-g-suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Exchange server, you could use mail flow rules to block the Google Doc.
I have test on my side, it works as expected:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!